# Does anyone know how to report the overall number of words using the wordcloud package in Python?

Tags: python, word-cloud

I only have the frequency for each word (see below), but how can I calculate how many certain words appear in my dataframe?

**code**

```
wordcloud1_EN = WordCloud(stopwords=comm_words, background_color="white",width=1800, height=1000,max_words=400,collocations=False,
                      relative_scaling = 0.4, colormap = "tab10", random_state = 42).generate(text1)
wordcloud1_EN.words_
```

**Report**

```
{'cut': 1.0,
 'paste': 0.5574728901461574,
 'redo': 0.2671852899575672,
 'free': 0.15346534653465346,...
```